# writing JavaScript with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to right some some JavaScript to define a variable using PHP.  The variable has a little jQuery in it which should get rendered by the client.  I say "should" but really mean I want it to. What should I do to make o2 the same as o1 (i.e. covert the jQuery)?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title></title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {
    var o1={"foo":{"bar": "abc/index.php?="+$("#id").val()}};
    console.log(o1);
<?php
$d='abc/index.php';
$json='{"foo":{"bar": "'.$d.'?id=\"+$(\"#id\").val()"}}';
//echo($json);
$json=json_decode($json);
//echo(print_r($json,1));
$json=json_encode($json);
//echo($json);

echo("var o2=".$json.";");
?>

console.log(o2);
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="123" />
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is rendered server side while javascript is rendered by the client (i.e. browser).  You'll need to send the json to a php script using ajax.

Comment: Are you getting this "123" value in your hidden input from PHP side? How are you printing this id? from something like $row['id']?

Comment: @Ryan.  Understand the ajax stuff.  Just want to use PHP to pre-write a variable to be available to the client.

Comment: @Oscar.  Yes, from PHP side.  I guess I can just write this variable directly into the json, but it is bugging me why this doesn't work.

Comment: @user1032531 Ok, then I think it will be easier, take a look at my answer maybe helps.

Comment: Maybe should have explained what I was trying to accomplish.  Upon loading of the page, I want to write the jquery.validate rules to the client using PHP.  The one that is giving me problems is the remote validation which uses ajax to call back to the server.  The reason I would like to use json is to simplify migrating the json from the typical jquery.validate client JS.  As such, it is opposite of the normal application where the client is sending json to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="123" />
```

So I can assume that you are getting that id from a db right? Maybe like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row[id];?>" />
```

If this is the case do the following (I tested and works):

You don't need hidden inputs to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title></title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {

    <?php
        //From your SQL query you obtained
        //$row['id'] = 123;
        $id = $row['id'];
    ?>

    var o1={"foo":{"bar": "abc/index.php?=" + <?php echo $id ?>}};
    console.log(o1);

    <?php
    $d='abc/index.php';
    $json='{"foo":{"bar": "'.$d.'?='.$id.'"}}';
    //echo($json);
    $json=json_decode($json);
    //echo(print_r($json,1));
    $json=json_encode($json);
    //echo($json);
    echo("var o2=".$json.';');
    ?>

    console.log(o2);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar,  I'm with you.  Just still curious why my original implementation didn't work.  I spent hours trying to get it to do so.  Thinking it might have been a striptag type of thing.

Comment: @user1032531 No problem :-) sometimes happens.

Comment: Thanks again Oscar.  Your solution works but still curious why my earlier attempt didn't. Any ideas why not?

Comment: @user1032531 Well, at first sight, jQuery can't be rendered in a simple PHP string as you expect when doing this: "$json='{"foo":{"bar": "'.$d.'?id=\"+$(\"#id\").val()"}}';" I think that was the error :-) but maybe someone around here will argue lol

Answer (score 0):

*Untested, may contain errors:*

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var o1={"foo":{"bar": "abc/index.php?="+$("#id").val()}};
    console.log(o1);

    <?php
    $d='abc/index.php';
    $json='{"foo":{"bar": "' . $d . '?="+$("#id").val()}}';

    echo("var o2=".$json.';');
    ?>

    console.log(o2);
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't if $json is first json_decode() and then json_encode().

Answer (score 0):

I prefer make json with the json_encode, to avoid unexpected problems with parse and validation of json.

the json_encode and json_decode only work with UTF-8, another charset will result in a blank string, if it has special chars.

```
<script>
<?php

$d = "abc/index.php";
$json['foo']['bar'] = $d . '?id=$("#id").val()';

echo "var o2 = ".json_encode($json);

?>
console.log(o2);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Roger, My definition of $json was very small, but the real one had many more variables and sub-variables.  Also, the original definition is based on a client only side application, and I wanted to just cut-and-past it with as little modification as possible.  Maybe a limitation of json_decode?