# How to pass data between two pages with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, query-string

I've seen several other questions on SO that are similar to this, but none of them are really what I'm looking for, so hopefully this won't be seen as a duplicate.

I have a client-side Javascript/HTML5 web application built with jQuery Mobile.  I am finding that performance can be quite slow and it was suggested that having too much going on in the DOM could be the cause.  My app does have several `data-role="page"` divs that could be bulking up the DOM in a single html page.  I'm trying to split my app into several html pages to improve performance, but I want the experience to be seamless for the user.  This means I will need to pass Javascript variables between the physical html pages within my app.

So far I've seen the following options in my searching:

1. Use a query string in the url going to the other pages. - I'm not sure I want my users seeing a what could be a rather large and confusing query string in the address bar.
2. Use server side code like ASP.Net or PHP to handle postback data. - I'm open to this, but I'm not really sure how it would work.  I don't want to convert my html pages to aspx or php files.  Could I have a simple server side script that could embed the postback data into a regular html file?
3. Use Cookies to store relevant data. - I'm not to sure of this one either because the majority of my users are in enterprise environments that may limit cookie usage.

Are there any other methods for accomplishing this?  At this point, I'm leaning toward some sort of server side processing.  If that is the best method, could someone point me in the right direction for figuring out how to do that?

Comment: jQuery Mobile performance issue is mostly due to the enormous styles associated with it. Strip down the stylesheet to exactly what you need and remove everything else.. Compress images.. Using multiple html files is not a good choice as it will surely interfere with the User Experience part.. Next time instead of jquerymobile, go with angular.js/backbone.js with bootstrap for templating..

Comment: I've been using dojo until now and I have to say jQuery Mobile already seems much less bulky.

Comment: :).. You will realize you were riding a school bus till now when u start using the js frameworks. Its so much faster and jquerymobile is nowhere near...

Answer (score 1):

Try out Local Storage or Session Storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Would local storage be just as likely to be restricted as cookies might be restricted in an enterprise environment?

Comment: Actualy, I never heard about such resrictions, so I dont have "boolean" answer. But I know that a lotof modern sites/apps use them

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com.

Answer (score 1):

Local Storage would be a way to go if you are HTML5 compliant. It will store values, reduce the calls to any server until you are actually ready to update all the info and the info will be present even when the browser is closed; use session storage or JS like this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
  return '';
};
```

if you need to clear local storage of sensitive info on closing the browser.

Remember that anything you pass into local storage will come out as a string so you will need to convert it to the appropriate data type when you get the info out of storage.

You'll also be limited to storing 5 megs of data (I believe that is standard) but you probably have other issues if your form requires that much info. :)

Check these out for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799(v=vs.85).aspx

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a POST instead of GET if you're only concern with the GET is the user seeing lengthy querystrings.

Comment: My other page would not be able to access the POST data with Javascript.  I would need some sort of server side script to handle that and then how would I get the data to the html page or Javascript?

Comment: Point taken. I'm a backend developer and forgot you only wanted client side if you could help it.

Comment: But you could also use sever side code to write your javascript or write values for javascript. I would go with the latter since it would require less server side code writing javascript blocks.

Comment: What would that look like?  Could I somehow inject a simple script tag in my HTML page that creates and assigns global variables?

Comment: Depends on which server side language you used. Place the a javascript block on your html and write the server side code to javascript variable. The following link shows this method in php.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677966/writing-javascript-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage. localStorage lets you store values in the browser.