# How to get text response from jquery get method?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am requesting a servlet to get a String value , for that I am doing like this.

```
function histryTraceFun(){
    $.get('SendNodeHistoryTracing?node='+temp,function(response){
        alert("in response "+response); // Here I am not getting response
        });
}
```

in servlet doGet() method I have,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String node=request.getParameter("node");


}
```

The controll will come to servlet but not returning to JSP , in callback function alert  the value of variable `response` is not comming. And actually I didnot understand how `response.setContentType()` work. can any one help me in this please. Thank you.

Comment: Because ,you are not printing anything from your servlet.

Comment: k . . I want the value of `node` in jsp page. how can I achive that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to send control back to your page :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourPage.html");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

You can also add data in response :

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("your_response");

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourPage.html");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Still problem then post me.

Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax#4113258), more understandable & explained code by [balusc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc).

Comment: K . . It solved my problem. I have small doubt. I am sending request to this servlet from jquery `get()` method. can we get the value of `node` in other jsp's javascript function?

Comment: Sorry actually I don't have any idea on it, but I am finding it. I ll post when I ll got the solution.

Comment: its k Thank u very much. If you find the solution please post me.

Comment: @Raghu : Are you for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933893/how-to-pass-data-between-two-pages-with-javascript

Comment: yes exactly., I used javascript `localstorage` concept

Comment: great... hope it helps.. :)